# How to test if a given series converges?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Given:

$$ \sum_{n=4}^\infty \left(\frac {10^nn!}{(3n)^n}\right)$$

Comment: What tests have you tried?

Comment: Ratio Test should work nicely. It will be useful to recall that $(1+1/n)^n\to e$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you consider the general term $$u_n=\frac {10^nn!}{(3n)^n}$$ and apply the ratio test, you have $$\frac{u_{n+1}}{u_n}=\frac {10^{n+1}(n+1)!}{(3(n+1))^{n+1}}\times\frac {(3n)^n}{10^nn!}=\frac {10}3 \Big(\frac n {n+1}\Big)^n=\frac {10}3 \frac{1}{\big(1+\frac 1n\big)^n}$$ So, for an infinite value of $n$, the limit of the ratio is just $\frac {10}{3e}\approx 1.22626 $ from which you can conclude.

You could repeat the same problem changing $3$ to any integer $k>3$ and conclude the opposite.

Answer (score 0):

Accordingly Stirling formula, if $n\to\infty$:
$$n!\sim\sqrt{2\pi n}\frac{n^n}{e^n}$$
So, we can transform $n$-th member to
$$\frac{10^n\sqrt{2\pi n}n^n}{n^n(3e)^n}\sim(10/(3e))^n\sqrt{n}$$
Now, we can see, that $10/(3e)>1$ and obviously the series is not convergence